# How do I get Facebook Group Events into WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, rss

The best way I have found to get Facebook Group Events into WordPress is to use Yahoo Pipes to create an RSS Feed. The feed that I have is as follows:

https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?Facebook_ID=1608419542769806&_id=1301d12f49b904e56afe3f420366a3c4&_render=rss

This works fine, but when I try to render this on a WordPress page with the Embed RSS plugin, it loads fine in the preview, but once it is inserted into the page, I receive the following error:

> **RSS Error:** A feed could not be found at
>   https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?Facebook_ID=1608419542769806&_id=1301d12f49b904e56afe3f420366a3c4&%23038;_render=rss.
>   A feed with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error, or
>   SimplePie was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed() if you are
>   certain this URL is a real feed.

Now, I can easily add the following code to my functions.php theme file:

```
add_action('wp_feed_options', 'force_feed', 10, 1);
function force_feed($feed) {
    $feed->force_feed(true);
}
```

but that just changes the error to:

> RSS Error: A feed could not be found at
>   https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?Facebook_ID=1608419542769806&_id=1301d12f49b904e56afe3f420366a3c4&%23038;_render=rss.
>   This does not appear to be a valid RSS or Atom feed.

Is there something I'm missing? All I want to do is spit out text onto a WordPress page of the Facebook Group Event details.

Answer (score 0):

There are different plugins for facebook streaming . Try the plugin '[custom-facebook-feed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-facebook-feed/)' . I think it will be the better option.

Comment: The Custom Facebook Feed WordPress plugin doesn't offer this functionality without upgrading to a Personal License and paying for it annually. This website I'm using this for is a non-profit and doesn't have a lot of money to throw at pulling in events dynamically.